# SSRS: Replacing User!UserID expression in subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

I've created a report in SSRS that uses the User!UserID Built-In Field to identify the user the user who is currently requesting the report, and then filters the data based on that user.

I now want to create subscriptions for the same report, so that the users don't have to request the report on-demand, but have it emailed to them instead.

However, since I'm the one creating the subscription, SSRS uses my user as the User!UserID, and does not give me the option to set the UserID as a parameter.

This is the way it should work:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx

> User dependent values in a report:
>
> > For standard subscriptions only, you can create subscriptions to reports that incorporate user account information in a filter or as text that appears on the report. In the report, the user account name is specified through a User!UserIDexpression that resolves to the current user. When you create a subscription, the user who creates the subscription is the considered the current user.

I can duplicate the report so that it doesn't use the logged in User, but it will mean maintaining two versions of the report.

Is there a way to identify whether the report is being run on-demand or as a subscription?
I could then use an if statement to either default the user to the login or leave it empty.

Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server do you have (e.g. 2008/2012, standard or enterprise)? If you have Enterprise edition you should take a look at Data Driven Subscriptions, you could pass the user id as one of the values from the subscription data.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I'm currently on 2012 Standard. Checking with IT if they can upgrade me. The Data Driven Subscriptions will definitely be easier than setting up the subscriptions one by one. I'm going through the tutorials now, but from what I see, I will still need a separate report to deal with the User variable. Correct?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156012.aspx: _You cannot create a data-driven subscription on a report that contains the User!UserID expression._ So, I may need to duplicate the report.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear - instead of using the User!UserID expression you would need to store the user's email address (for the subscription delivery) and their user ID as values in a table and then pass the User Id as a string parameter to the report.